# SQL Management Studio 2012 Foreign Key Is A Mess

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to add a foreign key to a table. I have created two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE madeupbusiness.staff
(
staffnum int NOT NULL,
forename varchar(30) NOT NULL,
surname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
meeting int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (staffnum),
)
GO
```

meeting should use the PK from from the meeting table to create a FK :

```
CREATE TABLE madeupbusiness.meeting
(
meetingnum int NOT NULL,
room varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (meetingnum),
)
GO
```

To create the foreign key I run this query

```
ALTER TABLE madeupbusiness.staff
WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_staff_meetingnum FOREIGN KEY (meetingnum)
REFERENCES madeupbusiness.meeting(meetingnum)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
GO
```

The query runs but when I create a database diagram there is a square loop the staff table from the staffnum key back onto it. Sorry but I don't really know how to describe it. There is no relationship between the two tables. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to add the relationship from design view but the foreign key table is greyed out.

Comment: There is no meetingnum column in the madeupbusiness.staff table the alter table should barf. It's a typo in the question or in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can rebuild the Table do this:

```
   CREATE TABLE madeupbusiness.meeting
   (meetingnum int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES madeupbusiness.meeting(YourColumnYouWantItShouldBeReferenced),
   room varchar(30) NOT NULL);
   GO
```

Comment: I'm new to SQL server. I did not realise you had to refresh the database when creating tables. That is why it was not picking up the PKs from other tables. Sorry for wasting peoples time.

Comment: You just have to REFERENCES to a valid Column in your REFERENCED TABLE